# Laravel 4 hosting on an online shared server

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4, shared-hosting

I have developed a website on l4 now I am trying to upload it on a shared server online. The app is accessible from a subdomain http://bookcheetah.thedevs.org or http://thedevs.org/bookcheetah but the only problem is that whenever you try to click around or search you are always getting 404 errors. I tried different ways like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683046/how-to-install-laravel-4-to-a-web-host-subfolder-without-publicly-exposing-app/16683938#comment25831529_16683938) and [this one](http://creolab.hr/2013/03/removing-the-public-segment-in-a-laravel-4-app/) but still I get 404 errors when I click around. Could it be the subdomain? Please help me resolve this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a .htaccess file in my document root with the following code:

```
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
```

That solved the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a issue with mod_rewrite. If you access your routes via index.php ie http://bookcheetah.thedevs.org/index.php/howitworks they appear to be working fine.

Check to see if mod_rewrite is enabled on the server and that your .htaccess file has the correct rules.

Comment: Thank you so much! atleast i can see my app work. I dont see any .htaccess file on the directory or even on the public_html directory. How do I check id mod_rewrite is enabled on a normal cpanel account?

Comment: Thanks, i created a .htaccess file in my document root with the mod_rewrite

Answer (score 3):

Just to get all answers in one place.

If you can access your pages in the manner dragoon mentioned (e.i. http://yourdomain.com/yoursubfolder/index.php/yourpage ) but when you try to access the same page without "/index.php" part you see "not found error" you might try to add in your .htaccess (in "/public" folder) file following line:

just after:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
```

add the following line (the trailing slash is important if you use stock .htaccess from Laravel) :

```
RewriteBase /yoursubfolder/
```

That should tell your web server to serve files from "yoursubfolder" as if they where in "/" base folder.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Hey, which subfolder did you mean?

Comment: @TechyTimo
Say you have a domain http://iamdomain.com/
and you want to serve your Laravel app from a subfolder /iamsubfolder
so the full path is http://iamdomain.com/iamsubfolder

then RewriteBase directive will be:
`RewriteBase /iamsubfolder/`