# Subdomain has redirect loop, Laravel in public_html folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a running laravel in public_html folder for www.mydomain.com, which is working fine. I have created a subdomain/folder inside public_html '/demo' where I uploaded 'index.html'. When I go to demo.mydomain.com, there is a redirect loop. I think laravel is not allowing me to do so. Should I add .htaccess file. Kindly help.

Comment: Propbably you should set your server configuration for that subdomain, to point to that folder. Laravel has nothing to do with this, requests are piped into your public_html folder, whatever subdomain you are using, that is why laravel will shown.

Comment: try this one [Source][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283155/deploy-laravel-4-app-in-a-subdomain

Let us know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file inside demo folder and add this

> RewriteEngine Off

And save it

Redirect loop is because all folders inside your laravel installations will use htaccess from laravel.. so basically you need to turn off or add new htaccess for other folders to work .. Hope you understand and it helps..