# uploading laravel project on subdomain on a live server

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to upload my laravel 4.2 project to live server. I have a domain( example.com). And I have subdomain(subdomain.example.com). This is my root directory.

[image]

All files are in blog_files except public folder. My public folder is in public_html/blog/ . I have changed two lines of my index.php as:

`require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';`
to
`require __DIR__.'/../../blog_files/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

and 
`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';`
to
`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../blog_files/bootstrap/start.php';`

error occured while trying to open the url(subdomain.example.com)/

Error:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I am following this suggestion.
[deploy laravel 4 app in a subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283155/deploy-laravel-4-app-in-a-subdomain)

Comment: I am not able to load bootstrap/autoload.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `bootstrap/path.php`

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../app',
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',
'base' => __DIR__.'/..',
'storage' => __DIR__.'/../app/storage',
```

Change these lines to

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../../blog_files/app',
'public' => __DIR__.'/../../public_html/blog',
'base' => __DIR__.'/../../blog_files',
'storage' => __DIR__.'/../../blog_files/app/storage',
```

**EDIT:**

Do not put public folder in directly in your `public_html/blog`. Just put the contents of the public folder in `public_html`.

And also use below as your `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: safallwa, still not working: `require(/home/vijayrana/public_html/blog/public/../../blog_files/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vijayrana/public_html/blog/public/index.php on line 22
`

Comment: try to implement my edits. those will work. @vijayrana

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Don't modify laravel files, just add an `.htaccess` inside `blog/`

File: `/home/vijayrana/public_html/blog/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
```

And point `subdomain.example.com` to `/home/vijayrana/public_html/blog/`

Comment: he has a folder named `public` in public_html/blog. Do u think this rewrite gonna work???