# Installing laravel4 public in httpdocs subfolder, not root

Tags: php, laravel-4

Much [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683046/how-to-install-laravel-4-to-a-web-host-subfolder-without-publicly-exposing-app/16683938#16683938), with a different folder structure, how would I be able to move the public laravel 4 under a subfolder in httpdocs?

My current structure is:

```
  domain.com
  | /other folder
  |_httpdocs
    |_laravel4core
      |_ app
      |_ bootstrap
      |_ / rest of the install
    |_public
      |_ index.php
```

My vhost is set to httpdocs/public, so when I load domain.com, the site directly loads public/index.php. However, without the correct configuration, it's a blank page.

I've tried modifying "bootstrap/paths.php" (attempting to move from dynamic to hard-coded)

```
// so this
'app' => __DIR__.'/../app', 
// to
'app' => '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/laravel4core/app', // so hard-coded
```

and app/config/app.php uri is set to domain.com (I've tried also domain.com/public).

Comment: Have you try a relative path `'app' => __DIR__.'/../_laravel4core/../app', ` ?

Comment: @Fractaliste, yes, and that did not work either.

Comment: Well, that's the way to go to change your folder paths. Please, be more specific when you say `that did not work either`.