# How to deploy laravel 4.2 on shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel-4, shared-hosting

I developed an application with laravel 4.2.8 and now I am having trouble deploying it. I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16683938/3153380 but its not working. I am getting a white screen and the headers are returning a 500 Internal Server Error status.

I read around that laravel 4.2 is a bit tricky to set up on shared hosting is this true? I can seem to find a working solution so those that have deployed 4.2 before please help. My folder structure is like below

> **root/**
>      **laravel_base/**
>          app/
>          ...
>      **public_html/**
>                  **siteroot/**
>                           assets/
>                           packages/
>                           uploads/
>                           index.php
>                           ...
>   Any pointers?

Comment: A "500 Internal Server Error" status code (or a blank page) means that your script is throwing an error but you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. That's something you need to fix before you go further; it's impossible to code properly without the aid of error messages. Here's a [brief explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680885/13508).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario thanks for the pointer. I got this error Warning: require(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/www/users/hosting_base/laravel_base/../../siteroot/bootstrap/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s):

Comment: If that's how the path looks like, your siteroot is outside your hosting_base.

Answer (score 18):

First make sure that your shared host runs `php` >= v5.4. Second try to follow this steps:

1. Create a folder outside your `public_html/` or `www/`. Ex: `project/`
2. Copy every folder and file (except the public folder) from your laravel app into that `project/` folder
3. Copy the content of `public/` folder into your `public_html/` or `www/` **(the .htaccess must be there too)**
4. Inside public/ locate the index.php file and change the following paths:

   a. Path to `autoload.php`

   ```
   require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
   ```

   *into*

   ```
   require __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/autoload.php';
   ```

   b. Path to `start.php`

   ```
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
   ```

   *into*

   ```
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/start.php';`
   ```

After all that it should be working.

Comment: I have created the folder outside de _'public_html'_ on my hosting and I have copied the **'public'** folder from my laravel projetc inside _'public_html'_. Now to access my app Do I need to specify the public folder too in the URL? I mean: **http://lenguajemx.com/public/**

Comment: it probably can be two things. 1) Do you have public_html/public? if so make it only public_html/{contents here} 2) Have you copied the .htaccess too?

Comment: Yes both aspects are true, I have `public_html/public` and I have already copied the `.htaccess` inside the _public_html/public_ folder. So I'm going to do it as you said. Thanks I'm gonna try it again.

Answer (score 4):

I did something similar to @Helder Lucas - I also had to edit the bootstrap/paths.php file:

```
# change: 'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',
'public' => __DIR__.'/../../public_html',
```

I created a script to setup laravel projects for shared hosting environments. Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/meganlkm/74dba6c4350ed58bf7bb

Comment: here is a new gist for laravel 5: https://gist.github.com/meganlkm/15ae87674642590172c5

Answer (score 1):

Try to play with `.htaccess`

In your `public_html`, add a `.htaccess` to forward the request

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^yoursite.com/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ yoursite.com/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

i.e.

```
public_html
├── yoursite.com    <-------- laravel project
├── .htaccess       <-------- this file
```

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty easy to get Laravel 4/5 running on OpenShift Online. For anyone else running into hosting issues, check out: https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/115-laravel-5-0

Comment: hey lucid, when will openshift support php 5.6?

Comment: OpenShift 3 supports PHP 5.6. Check out the OpenShift Online developer preview: https://www.openshift.com/devpreview/#technologies

Answer (score 0):

I just add a new folder in the / folder on my shared hosting

`www.domain.com`

Where i add a sub folder called

`public/`

So that the path looks like this

`/www.domain.com/public/`

And from the CPANEL i link the domain name root folder to the

`www.domain.com/public/`

And then i just upload the laravel application in

`/www.domain.com`

It works for laravel 4.2 and 5.
And there is no security breaches because the root domain folder is in the public folder of the laravel app, no need for updating the .htaccess file.

It just works.

Comment: i find this answer unclear. what should be the contents of public folder?

Comment: the laravel's public folder