# laravel routes goes directly to folder and file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I am using Laravel 4.2 for an web application. In my localhost everthing was fine but when I uploaded my application to the server the routes of laravel did not work.

For example I am going to **site.com/** and it opens the website, but when I go to **site.com/some_route** it tries gives me an 500 internal server error on the screen, and in the error logs I see **File does not exist:site.com/some_route**.

Also I can see internal folders of laravel from browser, I mean if I go to **site.com/app** browser opens the laravel's app folder.

In my main directory there is an **empty .htaccess** file, and in my public folder of laravel I have a .htaccess file includes following codes :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>

    Options -MultiViews

</IfModule>



RewriteEngine On



# Redirect Trailing Slashes...

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]



# Handle Front Controller...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I really need help here, because I am not good at .htaccess files and servers, so I stuck for hours.
Thank you

Comment: you need to install Laravel via composer/SSH.

Comment: It was just work fine on my localhost, I developed it more than one month, it was fine, can it be about server?

Comment: try adding RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
in your .htaccess after RewriteEngine On

Comment: have you set permissions well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to deploy on a shared hosting server.

[How to deploy laravel 4.2 on shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724586/how-to-deploy-laravel-4-2-on-shared-hosting) may help you, if you are on a shared hosting.