# Laravel 5.1 app causes script to run twice

Tags: php, laravel

I deployed a laravel app in a shared hosting. It is not designed to work in a shared hosting. I search in google on how to make it work and I added this htaccess script in the root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem I have for a while now is that some of my scripts are executed twice. Insertion in the database are duplicates. Can this htaccess cause the issue?

Comment: I would recommend to change `autoload.php` and `start.php` files not `htaccess` one. You can find how to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724586/how-to-deploy-laravel-4-2-on-shared-hosting

Comment: Thanks but it still the same. Does not work. I think i found the problem. It's in my keyboard, I guess. I tried to call the URL in command line via CURL and it's not anymore duplicating.