# upload my project laravel to a shared host

Tags: php, laravel, web-hosting, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting service hostinger.
as I can upload my laravel 5.2 and configure project?

and I tried using:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot() {
    //
}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register() {

    $this->app->bind('path.public', function () {
        return base_path() . '/public_html';
    });
   }
}
```

but still nothing.

Comment: Possibly dublicate ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724586/how-to-deploy-laravel-4-2-on-shared-hosting?rq=1

Comment: I have done successfully at Godaddy.

Comment: not duplicate, are different versions of laravel :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess easiest and better approach in this situation will be creating of a symlink between `public_html` and `public` folders. Example for Ubuntu/Debian:

```
ln -s /path-to-pub/public_html /path-to-pub/public
```

This solution is better because when you'll decide to move your project to VPN, dedicated server etc., you will not need to remember about any modifications you made and rewrite any code.

Comment: thank you for the advice. as I do the distribution of the laravel project folders?

Comment: If you have `/home/user543/public_html` directory structure, for example, upload your Laravel files into `user543` directory. So `public_html` and `public` directories will be in the same directory (on the same level).

Answer (score 1):

Put this code:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function () {
    return base_path() . '/public_html';
});
```

to `bootstrap/app.php` and You are good to go. (I assuming that You renamed `public` directory already.)

Comment: I put all my project folders inside public_html?

Comment: No. Just rename `public` directory to `public_html` if `public_html` is your document root.