# Uploaded Laravel to my shared hosting and I get forbidden on the domain

Tags: php, laravel

I know this question has been asked over and over but I can't get my head around it. Why isn't the project showing on the root domain, but do I have to always enter `/public` to it?

I've tried the command mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475891/upload-my-project-laravel-to-a-shared-host) (and also the tip in the comment). But that didn't work. And if I recall correctly forwarding all incoming requests to `/public/index.php?$1` is a potential security vulnerability because .env file can be shown exposing passwords and API keys.

I'm on a shared hosting environment using Laravel 5.2. How can I set this up?

Comment: Does the hosting provider allow you to upload files outside the http public dir? If not then I'd ask them if they can suggest anything, maybe you can have your virtual host (web server config) public dir path changed.

Comment: Shared hosting and Laravel isn't really an ideal situation.

Comment: I have a laravel setup on a shared hosting like this: all files and folders except `public` moved to a folder, then this folder goes into `public`, then paths are changed in `index.php` in `public` and like in the post you've mentioned. Then all the contents of `public` are uploaded to the shared hosting.