# Prevent access to .env file in Apache server?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new in laravel and I know the `.env` file is used to store database and email credentials. But when I'm opening `http://servername/.env` the `.env` file content is shown in browser.

Any chance to protect my database credentials without changing the file name to non-guessable one?

In case I'm using `.htaccess` to prevent file read, would this have negative effect to the laravel framework?

Comment: I'm not sure how did you set up your server, but you should only have the contents of the `public` folder public (for more info, [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16683938/908174)). If you do this, your issue is solved.

Comment: I don't do server setup before because I'm former CI developer trying to learn laravel. I've checked your answer and will try it. Thank you.

Comment: I think [How to secure Laravel .env file and file permission?](https://devnote.in/how-to-secure-the-env-file-in-laravel-using-file-permission/) is the best tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in production domain should be pointed to laravel project public folder where index.php file is, once it is done nobody can access .env file. if you are uploading project to showing demo to client don't upload .env file you can set evn parameter in .htaccesss file

**.htaccess file**

```
SetEnv APP_ENV local
SetEnv APP_DEBUG true
SetEnv APP_KEY app_keyasfassafas

SetEnv DB_HOST localhost
SetEnv DB_DATABASE db_name
SetEnv DB_USERNAME root

SetEnv CACHE_DRIVER file
SetEnv SESSION_DRIVER file
SetEnv QUEUE_DRIVER sync
```

**important apache env_module should be enable**

Comment: So this `.htaccess` will have same function as `.env` right? I'll try your suggestion if my server setting enabled env_module.

Comment: yest it works same as .evn more protected if you have project in sub directory not in  root of server.

Answer (score 19):

Please add below code in your .htaccess file. It works also in localhost and Live server.

```
# Disable Directory listing
Options -Indexes

# block files which needs to be hidden, specify .example extension of the file
<Files ~ "\.(env|json|config.js|md|gitignore|gitattributes|lock)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Bravo!!! You saved my life :) It works like charm. I am using laravel 5.7 version.

Comment: works globally for me on /etc/apache2/apache.conf...Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for how to stop .env files from being served on apache hence read.

do this on the `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` file - Ubuntu. 
after this part of that file
`<FilesMatch "^\.ht">`
        `Require all denied`
`</FilesMatch>`

add the code below

```
# Hide a specific file
<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

then restart your apache server with `sudo service apache2 restart` and enjoy!

Comment: That is a good way of globally disabling access to .env files. This code will work for all files that start with dot.
`<FilesMatch "^\.|\/\.">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>`

Answer (score 2):

in your .htaccess

past below line at end of .htaccess

```
<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Laravel .htaccess file


Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<Files .env>    <----------------at the end of .htaccess file
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```