# Hosting a laravel application

Tags: laravel

I'm new here. I've tried all I could but couldn't setup my laravel app. I've also tried the solutions provided here

[How to install Laravel 4 to a web host subfolder without publicly exposing /app/ folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683046/how-to-install-laravel-4-to-a-web-host-subfolder-without-publicly-exposing-app)

but I keep on getting HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.Any help please?

Comment: Check your error logs, or enable error reporting to try and get more information on what's erroring.

Answer (score 0):

change your host php version

PHP >= 5.4
MCrypt PHP Extension

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2#server-requirements

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/servers), it saves you a lot of time and you would support the creator

Comment: Thanks guys. It's my version of PHP.
And $array = []; also caused a lot of the problem. This isn't allowed in PHP5.3 i guess