# laravel 4 setting base url to /subfolder

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have deploy my laravel project in a subfolder following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683046/how-to-install-laravel-4-to-a-web-host-subfolder-without-publicly-exposing-app) link

I have done fine. It works fine when I write url in browser like `www.myproject.com/myurl`
Problem is when i click any link from my project it makes request to `www.myproject.com`
and get `error.`

What can I do now to make `www.myproject.com/myurl` my `base url` that whenever any request made, it goes through it?

Comment: Did you tried changing the Application URL in `/app/config/app.php`?

For example: `'url' => 'http://www.myproject.com/myurl/'`

Comment: I have tried but didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set base url to /subfolder in Laravel 4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127507/how-to-set-base-url-to-subfolder-in-laravel-4-2)