# Taking Laravel-5 project from Localhost to server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, hosting

I am new to laravel framework. Recently I have made a simple blog type website. In `localhost` it working good without any problems, if any problem arises then I used to do `composer update`, `composer dump-autoload`, etc.

But when I migrate it to the server got the following error. What is this error, should I have to run `composer update` again? If yes then how can I run it on my server. I have no idea on this matter, please help me.

```
Warning: require(/home/somedomain/public_html/CMS/app/http/helpers/backend/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/somedomain/public_html/CMS/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 58
```

And the next error is:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/somedomain/public_html/CMS/app/http/helpers/backend/helpers.php' (include_path='/home/somedomain/public_html/CMS/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/home/somedomain/public_html/CMS/vendor/phpunit/php-timer:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/somedomain/public_html/CMS/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 58
```

I am doing this project in Laravel5. If the error was due to `index.php` then here is my `index.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/CMS/bootstrap/autoload.php';



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/CMS/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

My main project directory is starting with `CMS` folder. In the same `CMS` directory I have a `index.php` and inside the `CMS` folder I have an `app`, `bootstrap`, `config`, `database`, `vendor` folder and many. When I remove all code of `index.php` and write `<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>` and go to my site `somedomain.com` I get `"Hello World`"`` as output. How to solve this error?

Comment: make sure your directory structures match on both localhost and public server. And make sure you're moving all files. Sounds like you forgot at least one.

Comment: make sure your storage folder in chmod 777

Comment: Is it a vps/dedicated server where you can run console commands?

Comment: and yes, you should run `composer update` again in order to install all dependencies

Comment: @manix. is it  laravel project working  in shared hosting ?

Comment: @vision, Not, it is not. Unless you can run shell commands

Comment: oh ok.thank you.then which hosting it works

Comment: You need a virtual machine to run laravel .  Perhaps create a droplet on Digital Ocean? If you need a cheap solution buy an unmanaged VM (you should know about server administration if you choose so) .Koding is also a free cloud based IDE that provides a small VM that you can experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you like to run your laravel project on a shared host this should be possible. Just upload the whole project including the `vendor` dir to your server.

Make sure that your domain points to the `public` folder inside your laravel project.
If you like to access your project inside a sub folder of your domain (e. g. `http://your-domain.com/your-app/`) then you need to make some changes. Here is a [how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683046/how-to-install-laravel-4-to-a-web-host-subfolder-without-publicly-exposing-app) for Laravel 4 which should work for L5 too.

If the error still occurs then make sure that your folders and files are in the correct upper/lower case. If your `localhost` is a windows machine (which makes no difference between upper and lower case) and you move to a linux server (which differentiates upper and lower case) you can run into problems. Therefore make sure your paths and filenames in your code are in the same upper/lower case as they are on your server.

To avoid problems like this I can recommend the use of [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead). It's a virtual machine environment for laravel development.

Comment: i have fixed error but my links are not working properly i got 404 error like this The requested URL /our-history was not found on this server.

Comment: please update your original question with detailed information and a good description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which server do you use ? Check if your path is defined in the config folder.
Also install all the dependencies in the right folder and copy all of them to your server. You can check this link for a proper installation https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals.
Most likely you're missing some files. Try reinstalling the project.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need to change the base path from localhost to your domain in order for it to work.
This worked for me though when i got the same error.

Comment: Try to improve your answer with explicative "code", if you can