# set site root in laravel 4 so / works properly

Tags: laravel-4

I have my laravel app inside www/mylaravelapp folder, and if I use `/` for home link, as in `<a href="/">HOME</a>`, for some reason it goes to `localhost`, not `localhost/mylaravelapp`.

Obviously it is not smart enough to do this on its own, so how do I tell it to?

Comment: Maybe this question is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683046/how-to-install-laravel-4-to-a-web-host-subfolder-without-publicly-exposing-app

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Best answer I found was on Laravel forum, basically if `/` is not working properly then use `url()` function which seems to work fine.

Comment: That's just bad if you keep hardcoding URLs

Answer (score 0):

A good practise of Laravel is always to name the routes you define on routes.php

For example:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'thisFunction@ThisController'));
Route::get('profile/{user}/edit', array('as' => 'user.edit', 'uses' => 'showEdit@UserController'));
```

And that way on your views, you can use:

```
<a href="{{ route('index') }}">HOME</a>
<a href="{{ route('user.edit', $user->id) }}">Edit profile</a>
```

And if one day you decide to change the URLs in the Routes, as long you don't rename them, you don't have to care about the links in the views, they will always be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice in laravel is to generate paths thru path gererator. I had a problem with routing when added parameter to url. For example `/main` worked fine, but in case of `/main/1` page styles crushed. Thats becouse `src` of includes have been changed from `domain/folder` on `domain/public/folder`. I know it do not hit subject directly, but [folder structure](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#paths) and [links](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls) do with helper methods to avoid that kind of problems